# Rails giving different type of results in raw sql query on prod and dev server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

When I am running direct raw sql using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, dev and prod servers are producing different type of results, although both are correct.

QUERY (in rails console):

```
query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT courses.name as course, round(count(placements.id)*100/count(students.id),2) as placed, count(placements.id) as total FROM courses LEFT JOIN students ON courses.id = students.course_id LEFT JOIN  placements ON placements.student_id = students.id where students.course_id<>1 group by course")
```

**DEV SERVER**:

```
 #<Mysql2::Result:0xab44ca4 @query_options={:as=>:array, :async=>false, :cast_booleans=>false, :symbolize_keys=>false, :database_timezone=>:utc, :application_timezone=>nil, :cache_rows=>true, :connect_flags=>-2147442171, :cast=>true, :default_file=>nil, :default_group=>nil, :adapter=>"mysql2", :pool=>5, :timeout=>5000, :encoding=>"utf8", :database=>"ietplacementdb_dev", :username=>"ietplacementuser", :password=>"placement@pass15", :socket=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", :flags=>2}>
```

*query.as_json*

```
[["M.C.A.", "2.0", 1], ["M.Tech.", "20.0", 2]]
```

**PROD SERVER:**

```
[{"course"=>"M.C.A.", "placed"=>0.0, "total"=>0, 0=>"M.C.A.", 1=>0.0, 2=>0}, {"course"=>"M.Tech.", "placed"=>0.0, "total"=>0, 0=>"M.Tech.", 1=>0.0, 2=>0}]
```

*query.as_json*

```
[{"course"=>"M.C.A.", "placed"=>0.0, "total"=>0, "0"=>"M.C.A.", "1"=>0.0, "2"=>0}, {"course"=>"M.Tech.", "placed"=>0.0, "total"=>0, "0"=>"M.Tech.", "1"=>0.0, "2"=>0}]
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the servers aren't identical in that case. Might be worth listing what is the same and what is different on them: ruby versions, gem versions (rails particularly), databases (different databases / different versions), how you're getting the output for query.as_json in each case (logging / console / `.to_s` / `.inspect`)

Comment: servers are SAME, i am doing it on my system in dev and prod environment, only db table records are different

Comment: So the _only_ difference is that it is development environment rather than production environment? You'll have to give us a little more to go on than that. What gems are in your dev environment but not in production maybe?